# C++ STL regular expressions with UTF-8 and Visual Studio 2013 (non-full UTF-8 support)

Tags: c++, regex, visual-studio-2013, utf-8, stl

I already got a solution to use regex iterators with a special iterator class for UTF-8 strings:

```
class u8iterator : public ::std::iterator<::std::input_iterator_tag, wchar_t>
{
    // …
    u8iterator(const char* pszUtf8);
    // …
    const wchar_t& operator *() const; 
    wchar_t& operator *(); 
    // …
    inline u8iterator& operator ++();
    inline u8iterator& operator --();
    inline u8iterator  operator ++(int);
    inline u8iterator  operator --(int);
    friend ptrdiff_t operator -(const u8iterator& lhs, const u8iterator& rhs);
    // …
};
typedef ::std::regex_iterator<u8iterator>::regex_type u8regex;
typedef ::std::regex_iterator<u8iterator>             u8regex_iterator;
typedef ::std::sub_match<u8iterator>                  u8sub_match;
```

Now my colleagues started to use the "simple" `::std::regex_search` and `::std::regex_replace`.
Is there a way to introduce UTF-8 as well?

This would have the advantage to have no need to convert from our internally used UTF-8 encoding to Unicode.

Any suggestion?

EDIT -----------------------------

I should have had posted more internals:

1. Yes - I'm working with Visual Studio 2013 on Windows.
2. the `++ operator` steps/iterates over byte sequences, converting one byte sequence into a stored wchar_t member, which is returned by the `cast operators`.
3. It seemed to be an "easy" way to get the regex work with UTF-8, without implementing more. So we have no need to convert internal UTF-8 and can use user provided Unicode patterns.

The problem is not in using the u8iterator/u8regex/u8regex_iterator/u8sub_match!

The problem is, that the variant of regex_replace allowing to use the u8iterator … (simplified)

```
OutIter regex_replace(OutIter outIter, InIter firstIter, InIter lastIter, Regex regexp, String replacement, Enum flags)
```

… needs an out-iterator for a buffer accepting the changes.

I have no idea in how to implement an output iterator, accepting the wchar_t sequences, converting and appending UTF-8 byte sequences.

May be … I should simply use a std::wstring back_insert iterator in regex_replace accept, that I have to convert the resulting Unicode/UCS-2 string back into UTF-8 while there is no need to convert the UTF-8 source text into Unicode/UCS-2.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Using `wchar_t` for [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) seems odd to me, as as [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) uses *8-bit bytes*  for its encoding.

Comment: You mention VS so am guessing Windows; so if `const wchar_t& operator *() const;` is dereferencing a UTF-8 code point it will need to return multiple `wchar_t` as Windows is UTF-16 and a Unicode code point my take up to 2 UTF-16

Comment: @RichardCritten "UTF-8 code point" there's no such beast. There are Unicode code points, and there are UTF-8 code units.

Comment: You may want to look at how [utf8-cpp](https://sourceforge.net/projects/utfcpp/) works and maybe use it.